# Angular and jquery click functions

Tags: jquery, angularjs

So I have an html code that uses angular's ng-click function

```
<div class="folder_icon" ng-click="selectFolder()">.....
```

And my selectFolder() function looks like this:

```
$scope.selectFolder = function () {
    $(".folder_icon").click(function () {
        if ($scope.folder_select == false) {
            $(this).parent().closest('div[class^="folder_nr_"]').css({
                'border': 'solid',
                'border-width': '1px',
                'border-color': '#ff7d43',
                'box-shadow': '0 0 20px #ff7d43'
            });
            $scope.folder_select = true;

        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().closest('div[class^="folder_nr_"]').css({
                'border': '',
                'border-width': '',
                'border-color': '',
                'box-shadow': ''
            });
            $scope.folder_select = false;
        }
    });
};
```

When I use this function I need to click twice because of angular ng-click and $.jQuery.click() functions. Can I make my function same but without jquery click function?

Comment: You can... what you're doing is considered bad practice tho - dont mix Angular and jQuery. The reason it takes 2 clicks is because on the first click you call your Angular function, which creates the jQuery click handler. The second click again calls the Angular function - but also calls the jQuery handler since it now exists.

Comment: Yes. You're already saying "when the user clicks this, do this." You don't need it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing this the Angular way - and it's really quite simple. First, make a class with your CSS rules you're applying above:

```
.myClass {
    border: solid
    border-width: 1px
    border-color: #ff7d43
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ff7d43
}
```

Now, apply this class to your element via `ngClass` and a bool variable (`folder_select`)

```
<div ng-class="{'myClass': folder_select}"></div>
```

Now, when `$scope.folder_select` is true, this class is applied. Now update your Angular:

```
$scope.selectFolder = function () {
    $scope.folder_select = !$scope.folder_select;
}
```